# npm install firebase always fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, npm, npm-install

when I tried to install firebase it always fails. I wanna to install firebase in my REACTJS project using

```
`npm i firebase`
```

and shows this error:
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! path G:\react\netflix\netflix-clone\node_modules\youtube-player\node_modules\debug\src
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'G:\react\netflix\netflix-clone\node_modules\youtube-player\node_modules\debug\src'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'G:\react\netflix\netflix-clone\node_modules\youtube-player\node_modules\debug\src'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'G:\react\netflix\netflix-clone\node_modules\youtube-player\node_modules\debug\src'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -4048,
npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!     path: 'G:\react\netflix\netflix-clone\node_modules\youtube-player\node_modules\debug\src'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'G:\react\netflix\netflix-clone\node_modules\youtube-player\node_modules\debug\src',
npm ERR!   parent: 'youtube-player'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-09-20T07_03_09_714Z-debug.log

my package.json file is here :

```
{
  "name": "netflix-clone",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "movie-trailer": "^2.0.6",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "react-youtube": "^7.12.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share the ```package.json``` code

Comment: use powerShell (Admin), cmd not permissions

Comment: Have you tried ```npm cache clean --force```?

Comment: @Amr i accidently tried it yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a permission issue.
What you can do is that open command line(CMD) as an administrator by right clicking on command line(CMD) and selecting "Run as Administrator".
Once it is opened then navigate to your project folder and then install firebase. Image is added for windows but if you have **MAC** then do it correspondingly!

[image]